# How to import .py file as a module in .pynb?

Tags: python, import

[I am not able to load the .py file (adspy_shared_utilities) as module though it has been placed at same level and folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDXn.png)

Comment: Hi @Ujwal, could you please post your code instead of linking snapshots? Also have a look at [what can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), seeking for debug advice without showing any effort normally causes questions to be downvoted or removed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace suggests that the error is occuring inside the "adspy_shared_utilities.py" file. This means importing that file works fine, but there is another error in that file. You are trying to use `import graphviz`, but the interpreter cannot find the `graphviz` library. Try installing graphviz into your environment: `pip install graphviz`.